# Python MixIn standards

Tags: python, design-patterns, mixins

So I'm writing some code and have recently come across the need to implement a few mixins. My question is, what is the proper way to design a mix-in? I'll use the example code below to illustrate my exact query.

```
class Projectile(Movable, Rotatable, Bounded):
    '''A projectile.'''
    def __init__(self, bounds, position=(0, 0), heading=0.0):
        Movable.__init__(self)
        Rotatable.__init__(self, heading)
        Bounded.__init__(self, bounds)
        self.position = Vector(position)

    def update(self, dt=1.0):
        '''Update the state of the object.'''
        scalar = self.velocity
        heading = math.radians(self.heading)
        direction = Vector([math.sin(heading), math.cos(heading)])
        self.position += scalar * dt * direction
        Bounded.update(self)

class Bounded(object):
    '''A mix-in for bounded objects.'''
    def __init__(self, bounds):
        self.bounds = bounds

    def update(self):
        if not self.bounds.contains(self.rect):
            while self.rect.top > self.bounds.top:
                self.rect.centery += 1
            while self.rect.bottom < self.bounds.bottom:
                self.rect.centery += 1
            while self.rect.left < self.bounds.left:
                self.rect.centerx += 1
            while self.rect.right > self.bounds.right:
                self.rect.centerx -= 1
```

Basically, I'm wondering, are mix-ins sort of like Java interfaces where there is a sort of (in Python's case implicit) contract that if one wishes to use the code one must define certain variables / functions (not unlike a framework), or is it more like the code I've written above, where each mix-in must be initialized explicitly?

Comment: I don't know that this is a rule but it's unusual in Python to have nonlinear `__init__`ing. I would limit one base class, the "true" parent, to having and `__init__` method. Also, as your example is written, you never call `Bounded.update()`.

Comment: Yeah, wrote the example up a little too fast. Regarding your point about __init__ though, does that suggest mix-ins ought not have to __init__ (in which case, they come with contracts)?

Comment: I really don't know about "ought not" -- but in Python, it's certainly the way I would do it. I didn't post it as an answer because it was an opinion. I'm not sure you're going to get an answer to this that _isn't_ opinion (the one below is just off-topic) so let me know if you want to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both behavior in Python. You can force the reimplementation by using Abstract Base Classes, or by raising NotImplementedError in virtual functions.

If **init** are important in parent's classes, then you have to call them. As eryksun said, use the `super` builtin function to call the parent's initializers (this way, an initializer for a given class will only be called once).

Conclusion: depends on what you have. In your case, you have to call **init**, and you should use `super`.